# angular module.run ReferenceError: $location is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting

I want to AngularJS Change Path Without Reloading, look http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/

in core.js:

```
 'use strict';
    angular.module('App',['ngRoute'])
        .run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
        var original = $location.path;
        $location.path = function (path, reload) {
            if (reload === false) {
                var lastRoute = $route.current;
                var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                    $route.current = lastRoute;
                    un();
                });
            }
            return original.apply($location, [path]);
        };
    }]);
```

In controller:

```
    angular.module('App')        
        .controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$location',  function($scope) {
  $scope.changeURL = function(){
            console.log("IN changeURL");
            $location.path('/sample/gfshdfdsf', false);
        };      
    }]);
```

If invoke changeURL, it will occur error:`ReferenceError: $location is not defined`

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

$location is not injected in the `controller`, so just change

```
.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$location',  function($scope)
```

to

```
.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '$location',  function($scope, $location)
```

Comment: Thanks you. I changed, but new error: TypeError: $location.path is not a function.

Comment: change `$location.path('/sample/gfshdfdsf', false);` to `$location.path('/sample/gfshdfdsf');`

Comment: sorry, $location.path = function (path, reload)  is defined in .run

Comment: I must call $location.path('/sample/gfshdfdsf', false) to change url without reload. It define in core.js.  But occur error : TypeError: $location.path is not a function.

Comment: Can you try `$location.path('/sample/gfshdfdsf').replace().reload(false)`

Comment: Can you see this http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/ ? I copy the code from it. I don't know why it occur error.

Comment: I will be glad to have a look on it but could you please post it in a new question , since I already provide you an answer to the original question. Its better to keep the post clean for future users. Thanks

Comment: Thank you , i post it in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014504/angularjs-how-to-call-function-in-service) with some changes. Looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and I deleted the $rootScope from the definitions. After that it worked. No idea why.

Not working

```
app.factory("OrganizationService",   
    ['$q', '$http', '$log', '$location', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'LoadSubscriptionsService', 'LoadRolesService',
  function($scope , $http, $log, $location, $cookies, $rootScope, $timeout) {
```

Working

```
app.factory("OrganizationService",   
    ['$q', '$http', '$log', '$location', '$timeout', 'LoadSubscriptionsService', 'LoadRolesService',
  function($scope , $http, $log, $location, $cookies, $timeout) {
```